# Как скомпилировать программу под обе архитектуры x64 и x32

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

Вопрос такой: Как скомпилировать программу сразу для двух архитектур, код на с++, что бы был один exe и запускался как на x64 так и на x32, сейчас использую windows 10 x64 и компилятор MinGW. Для примера взял freeglut. Могу показать код но это не так важно так как интересует не сам код а именно процесс компиляции.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, формат PE может быть или под x32 или под x64, но не под обе одновременно. И там и там запускается x32. Или делайте одну сборку под x32 или придется делать лаунчер, который будет определять архитектуру и запускать нужную версию основного exe.

Comment: Так делают тулзы sysinternals. exe один, но на старте из основного создаётся временная копия нужной архитектуры и запускается.